# Why Magento 2 doesn't export all attribute data?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, When I try to export all product data then some attribute those are created by me doesn't get exported?

Is there any setting I need to do for an attribute to get exported? Please help me.

Comment: from where you are exported data ?

Comment: @Yogesh
From Magento backend  System -> Export ,
Entity Type = Products,
Export File Format = CSV
& just click continue to get all product data with attribute values